# Emacs: Octave Sending lines C-c i l doesn't work

Tags: octave, emacs24

I just setup Octave on my Emacs, however I have no idea how to send lines to the Octave buffer...

After M-x run-octave
My cursor is on the line a = 1
I typed `C-c i l` it doesn't work..

1) `C-c C-i` then it shows:
C-c TAB is undefined ---------- Why C-i is recognized as TAB here??

2) `C-c i` then it shows:
C-c i is undefined

both warnings shine before I even type in `l`!

Anyone could help? Much appreciated for any response!

PS
My octave-mod.el file has the definition:

```
 (define-key map "\C-c\C-il" 'octave-send-line)
```

Answer (score 3):

The keybindings mentioned online are outdated. `'octave-send-line` is now `C-c TAB C-l`
You can find all the keybindings by `C-h m( or F1 m)`. I have pasted some of them below for quick reference. Happy Emacs Editing

```
C-c TAB C-b octave-send-block
C-c TAB C-f octave-send-defun
C-c TAB C-h octave-hide-process-buffer
C-c TAB C-k octave-kill-process
C-c TAB C-l octave-send-line
C-c TAB C-r octave-send-region
C-c TAB C-s octave-show-process-buffer
C-c TAB b   octave-send-block
C-c TAB f   octave-send-defun
C-c TAB h   octave-hide-process-buffer
C-c TAB k   octave-kill-process
C-c TAB l   octave-send-line
C-c TAB r   octave-send-region
C-c TAB s   octave-show-process-buffer
```

Comment: I guess maybe my Octave is too old.. That was 3.2 or something. Now I installed 3.6.4 and it works great!

Comment: If an answer here satisfactorily solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it. The same applies to any other question you have asked or may ask in the future. You even get two reputation points! If you want more information, you can look at this Meta post: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/238586).